# Word doc created in previous ubuntu not usable after upgrading

Tags: upgrade

It now looks like this...

```
       ÿÿÿÿ                                        â[      W o r d D o c u m e n t                                                     ÿÿÿÿ                                        ;(        S u m m a r y I n f o r m a t i o n                           (   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                    K             D o c u m e n t S u m m a r y I n f o r m a t i o n           8       ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                    S             C o m p O b j                                                     ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                        q                                                                           ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                                    þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ  þÿ
```

ÿÿÿÿ        À      F¬   Microsoft Office Word Document 
   MSWordDoc     Word.Document.8 ô9²q

Answer (score 1):

Word files get corrupted, sometimes when they're copied. It's an incredibly complex format. Is it a .DOC, .DOCX, .DOCM or some other format?  However, there is a [step-by-step procedure](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/microsoft-word-recover-corrupt-files.html) for .DOCX/.DOCM files because, deep down, the .DOCX/.DOCM files are really .ZIP files - and if you make a copy of the Word file and rename it with a .ZIP extension, you can then open it up and perform surgery on it.